# apache server can't write to logs

Tags: python, django, apache, permissions

Not certain if this belongs here or on SU

I'm developing a Django app and I'm having a problem with logfiles.  I have a logger configured to write to `/var/log/django/django.log`.  When I try to start the server, I get a 500 error, and the error log says

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'djangologfile': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/django/django.log'
"httpd/error_log" 480L, 61112C
```

The permissions for both `django.log` and the `django` directory are 777.  Why can't the server write to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easy way to test this is to sudo as a user the server is running under and try to ls /var/log/django/django.log. If that fails you might get insight into what the problem is.

Comment: Well, how do I determine what user the server is running as?

Comment: It would be in the server config (in Apache config look for User directive in the main config file) or you can just use ps aux and look for the server process.

Comment: the config says the user is `apache`. `su - apache` returns `This account is currently not available.`.  I've changed all directories in the path to `/var/log/django/django.log` to give write access to this user, but there is still no change

Comment: what do you use to run a django app under apache? mod_wsgi?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it is possible for mod_wsgi to run WSGI processes under some user other than the main apache user. Check for that in your config.